# How can I smoothly merge two cylinders that intersect at an angle using 3D Maya?

Tags: 3d, maya, modeling

I am a beginner using 3D Maya, and I am trying to merge two cylinders at an angle smoothly, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I don't know what the proper terminology for this action is, so I have been unsuccessful in looking for a solution online.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to need to use the target weld tool under the Mesh Tools in the menu bar. Then select the source object and drag to your second object.

Here is a link with a detailed [tutorial](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/GUID-F1BFED46-9277-4B01-93A8-37946E110007-htm.html).